# Show click count for each button and the sum

Tags: javascript, button, count, onclick

I want to be able to show the onclick count for button#1, button#2, and show the sum of clicks for button#1+button#2. So far all I have been able to show is the sum.

HTML

```
 <button id="1" onclick = "countCar('ferrari');">Button#1</button>
 <a>Ferraris</a><span id="ferrariCount"></span>

 <a id="showSum">SUM<span id="carCount"></span></a>

 <button id="2" onclick = "countCar('toyota');">Button#2</button>
 <a>Toyotas</a><span id="toyotaCount"></span>
```

Javascript

```
  var carCount = 0; 
  var ferrariCount = 0;
  var toyotaCount = 0;
  function countCar(type)

  {
    carCount = carCount + 1;
    document.getElementById('carCount').innerHTML = carCount;

    ferrariCount = ferrariCount + 1;
    toyotaCount = toyotaCount + 1;

     if(type =='ferrari'){document.getElementById('ferrariCount').innerHTML = ferrariCount;
             }else{
             document.getElementById('toyotaCount').innerHTML = toyotaCount;}
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit redundant so I'd structure it like this:

```
var counts = {
  'ferrari': 0,
  'toyota': 0,
  'total': 0
};

function countCar(type) {
  document.getElementById('carCount').innerHTML = ++counts['total'];
  document.getElementById(type + 'Count').innerHTML = ++counts[type];
}
```

Instead of using a ton of global variables, just create and object to store your numbers in there. It makes your code cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: I am very new to programming thank you for the lesson/insight. It worked too. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. If you're confused about any part, just ask. I think I might've made it a bit too condensed.

Comment: I am a bit confused by the 'Count' part of what you wrote in the last line. Can you explain the use of 'Count'.

Comment: Your elements all have similar `id` attributes: `ferrariCount` and `toyotaCount`. You can generalize this and say the `id` of any of those elements is equal to `car_manufacturer + 'Count'`, which is what I did in the code.

Answer (score 0):

And change

document.getElementById('toyotaCount').**innterHTML** = toyotaCount;}

Comment: And the ferraiCount part. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

if(type = '1')

Why you are using this?

It should change to

if(type === 'ferrari') and it will work then.

Also its innerHTML some typo